# "Error: Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`."

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a simple histogram with ggplot2 package in R.
I'm loading my data from a csv file and putting 2 of the columns together in a data frame, like this:

```
df = data.frame(sp = data$species, cov = data$totalcover)
```

sp is recognised as a factor of 23 levels (my number of lines) and cov as 23 numbers.
Then, to build the histogram, I'm executing this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(df$sp, df$cov) + geom_histogram())
```

However, R returns the error: "Error: Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`."

How is this possible if I'm already using aes? Is it maybe related with the type of the values?

Comment: You shouldn't use `$` inside of `aes()`. Also histograms are univariate plots so you don't specify a y variable for those. Is your data already summarized? Maybe you want a bar chart? Try `ggplot(df, aes(sp, cov) + geom_col()`. If you the same message then it's possible you've overwritten the default `aes()` function. Take a look at `conflicts()` to see if you are shadowing the `ggplot2::aes` function.

Comment: Thank you very much!  geom_col() does actually what I want and it doesn't return any error, so I think I haven't overwritten anything XD

Comment: The `Error: "mapping" must be created by "aes()"` might also occur if by mistake you use a pipe `%>%` instead of a plus `+` before the call to `geom_...()`.

Answer (score 58):

I had the same error, even if I was using `aes()`. So I used `mapping` argument before `aes()`.

```
ggplot() +
geom_boxplot(df, mapping = aes(x = sp, y = cov))
```

Answer (score 15):

Two mistakes:

1. Brackets have to be closed after ggplot and calling histogram comes after
2. you specify your data set when you call ggplot on `df`. Therefore there is no need to add `df$sp`. `sp` is enough.

This code should work (if there is nothing wrong with your data):

```
    ggplot(df, aes(sp, cov)) + geom_histogram()
```

Comment: And in fact, using `$` references inside of `aes()` can create hard to diagnose cases where data are plotted in the incorrect order (or with mismatched labeling, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Do not use $ in aes. Only specify the dataset in ggplot. I used `plot<-df %>% ggplot()`

Comment: Do you want to expand your answer a little to show how to specify the variables in the aes() command? That will help those will more than two variables in their data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works . You should not use the dollar sign $ if you have specified the data already. I had the same problem and when I removed the dollar sign, it worked.

```
ggplot(dat1, aes(Q84, REGION, fill = Q3)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Identity") +
  facet_grid(REGION ~ Q84)
```

Avoid this:

```
ggplot(dat1, aes(dat1$Q84, dat1$REGION, fill = Q3)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Identity") +
  facet_grid(dat1$REGION ~ Q84)
```

where `dat1` is the name of my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ggplot(df, aes(df$sp, df$cov))+ geom_histogram()
```

instead of

```
ggplot(df, aes(df$sp, df$cov) + geom_histogram())
```

displacement of brackets

Answer (score 0):

As another potential solution, I found that having library(cowplot) and library(ggplot2) loaded at the same time made "ggsave("test.pdf", p1)" not work.

Instead, use the cowplot syntax "save_plot("test.pdf", p1)"

Answer (score 0):

The main error is that you closed the bracket at the wrong place this is because we added geom.histogram as new function not an argument of ggplot.
Instead, try below code

ggplot(df, aes(df$sp, df$cov)) + geom_histogram()